# How to add a new entry to fstab?

Tags: linux

I mount a device `mount /dev/xvdf /mnt/mongo` and verify the mount using `df-h`:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on  
/dev/xvda1            7.9G  955M  6.9G  12% /  
tmpfs                 299M   44K  299M   1% /dev/shm  
/dev/xvdf              20G  589M   19G   4% /mnt/mongo
```

But now I'm trying to figure out how to make it auto mount on boot.

I understand I need to add a new entry to `/etc/fstab`, so I perform:

```
$ sed -i '$ a\/dev/xvdf /mnt/mongo xfs defaults 1 1' /etc/fstab
```

But, after reboot, it seems that the auto mount didn't work. The device didn't appear in the `df -h` list.

Should I not use the `sed` to add the entry? Is the entry I entered incorrect?

Comment: What distribution are you using? Stupid question but did you use `sudo`? Also the question is probably best directed at the [*nix Q&A Forum](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: the easier way would be to edit the file directly with `nano /etc/fstab` as root, or `sudo nano /etc/fstab` if sudo is enabled or if you are using ubuntu.

Comment: Yes, I use `sudo`.  I didn't know `nano`, it helped me for editing the file, thanks!

Comment: What do `dmesg` show? (And what Linux system are you using?)

Answer (score 1):

Sed is fine, but not ideal for what you're doing. Sed is more for when you just want a user to paste something to the terminal. Like the comments said, you can edit the file using nano or if you prefer the GUI you can use gedit, kate, or whatever your preferred editor is.

To get the filesystem to mount at boot, under the options field you want "auto" So your line should look like `/dev/xvdf /mnt/mongo xfs defaults,auto 1 1`

Comment: I changed my entry to: `/dev/xvdf /mnt/mongo xfs defaults,auto,noatime,noexec,nodiratime 0 0` and reboot, and still - it didn't auto mounted the device. I'm using Amazon EBS device, does it matter?

Comment: I used these settings, as written in the official mongodb docs for linux with ebs: [http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Amazon+EC2](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Amazon+EC2)